# calculate percentages of levels - add column name

Tags: r

This code:

```
tips <- data.frame(
        gender = c("female", "male", "male")
        ,smoker = c("yes", "no", "no")
     )

tblFun <- function(x) {
    tbl <- table(x)
    res <- cbind(tbl, round(prop.table(tbl) * 100, 2))
    colnames(res) <- c('Count', 'Percentage')
    res
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(tips[1:2], tblFun))
```

produces this:

```
       Count Percentage
female     1      33.33
male       2      66.67
no         2      66.67
yes        1      33.33
```

which is great. However, I would like to produce this:

```
key_value_pair       Count Percentage
gender=female     1      33.33
gender=male       2      66.67
smoker=no         2      66.67
smoker=yes        1      33.33
```

Could someone please be so kind and suggest a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `tidyverse` and some data manipulation:

```
library(tidyverse)

tips %>%
    gather(key_value, value) %>% # wide to long
    count(key_value, value) %>%
    group_by(key_value) %>%
    mutate(percentage = n / sum(n)) %>%
    unite(key_value_pair, key_value, value, sep = "=") # convert 2 cols into 1

#   key_value_pair     n percentage
#   <chr>          <int>      <dbl>
# 1 gender=female      1      0.333
# 2 gender=male        2      0.667
# 3 smoker=no          2      0.667
# 4 smoker=yes         1      0.333
```

Comment: I like this - amazing!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to expand your `tblFun` function to accept the category name and prepend it to the labels.

```r
tblFun <- function(x, nm = character(0)) {
  tbl <- table(x)
  if (length(nm)) names(tbl) <- paste(nm[[1]], names(tbl), sep = "=")
  res <- cbind(tbl, round(prop.table(tbl) * 100, 2))
  colnames(res) <- c('Count', 'Percentage')
  res
}
```

Given no change, it behaves as before:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(tips[1:2], tblFun))
#        Count Percentage
# female     1      33.33
# male       2      66.67
# no         2      66.67
# yes        1      33.33
```

In order to pass each column's name with each column, you need to use the multi-argument version of `lapply`, `Map`:

```r
do.call(rbind, Map(tblFun, tips[1:2], names(tips[1:2])))
#               Count Percentage
# gender=female     1      33.33
# gender=male       2      66.67
# smoker=no         2      66.67
# smoker=yes        1      33.33
```

---

An alternative is to use `purrr::imap`, which passes both the object *and its name* (as a second argument) to the function:

```r
do.call(rbind, purrr::imap(tips[1:2], tblFun))
#               Count Percentage
# gender=female     1      33.33
# gender=male       2      66.67
# smoker=no         2      66.67
# smoker=yes        1      33.33
```

One advantage I see is no need to include both `tips[1:2]` and `names(tips[1:2])`, though if you aren't already using `purrr` or tidyverse-packages, then adding another package just for this might not be desired (esp when `Map` does the same thing with the explicit `names()`).

---

As a brief demonstration of what `Map` is doing: it "zips" arguments together.

As a comparison, `lapply` (and family) run a function once for each element of its input vector/list. So `lapply(1:3, myfunc)` "unrolls" to

```r
list(
  myfunc(1),
  myfunc(2),
  myfunc(3)
)
```

If you try to provide multiple vectors, however, it does not perform as one "might" want/think: `lapply(1:3, myfunc, 11:13)` unrolls to:

```r
list(
  myfunc(1, 11:13),
  myfunc(2, 11:13),
  myfunc(3, 11:13)
)
```

`Map` does it for an arbitrary number of vectors/lists, so `Map(myfunc, 1:3, 11:13, 21:23, 99)` unrolls to

```r
list(
  myfunc(1, 11, 21, 99),
  myfunc(2, 12, 22, 99),
  myfunc(3, 13, 23, 99)
)
```

(Notice how length-one vectors are recycled. Though it does do recycling of lengths between 1 and the length of the longest vector, I don't recommend relying on it unless you strictly control the fact that the shorter vectors should multiply out to the length of the longest with no remainder.)

`myfunc` in this case must accept (at least) three arguments. Two notable differences between `lapply` and `Map`:

- `lapply` puts data-first, function-second; because `Map` accepts *one or more* vectors/lists, it puts the function-first, one-or-more data second+;
- `Map` will recycle a singular `list` argument, so `Map(myfunc, 1:3, list(11:13)` unrolls to `list(myfunc(1, 11:13), myfunc(2, 11:13), myfunc(3, 11:13))`, which on the surface looks very similar to `lapply(1:3, myfunc, 11:13)` but can be handy when you have more than two vectors of inputs.
- Because it doesn't care how many vectors/lists, one can send arbitrary/unknown lengths of vectors/lists to `Map` with `do.call`, as in

  ```r
  l <- list(1:3, 11:13, 21:21)
  do.call("Map", c(f = myfunc, l))
  ```

  (as long as `myfunc` accepts arbitrary number of arguments, likely via `...` mechanics). The first and only named argument of `Map` is `f=` for the function; it isn't required to name it here, but I like to for clarity.
- Just like `lapply` has the optionally-simplifying version `sapply`, `Map` has the optionally-simplifying version `mapply`. I tend to prefer explicit -- there's nothing more frustrating than expecting vector output but one input causes the output to be a `list` ...

Comment: I'm not the op but this works really well. @r2evans would you mind to tell me what `Map` is actually doing? I'm quite not sure even with ?Map. Thank you.